# Pass a std container to a function

Tags: c++, containers

I came up with the following:

```
template <typename T> inline void printcontainer( std::vector<T> container )
{
    for( auto it = container.begin(); it != container.end(); it++ )
    {
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;
    }
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(5);
    v.push_back(4);
    v.push_back(3);
    printcontainer(v);

    return 0;
}
```

(Sorry for the `push_backs`, visual studio doesn't accept initializer lists...ugh!!)

now this function is limited to `std::vector`, how can I make it so that I can pass other containers, like `std::list` arrays etc...

Comment: What version of VC++ are you using that doesn't support initializer lists?

Comment: visual studio 2012, things like `std::vector<int> v {1,2,3};` isn't supported so you have to use the c-style array workaround which I quite despise. Also it doesn't have `std::initializer_list` pretty weird eh.

Comment: Right, I've gotten so used to c++11 that I forgot that VS adopted many/most? c++11 features not before VS 2013.

Comment: @ViniyoShouta You might want to try Visual Studio 2015, it supports initializer lists (even VS2013 does). There is a free community edition (all features from Pro version). This will allow you to use many modern C++ features.

Comment: Yeah I've downloaded that, but I'm using windows 7...says I must have a higher windows version

Comment: @ViniyoShouta - You should be able to use VS2015 on Windows 7, but you must be on Win7 SP1.

Comment: Note that your code copies (or moves) the container while the two answers don't. This may change the semantics when e.g. `T` is not copyable or container is modified inside the function.

Comment: @pstrjds VS2015 definitely works in Win7SP1.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply don't template on the type stored by the container, but on the type of the container itself:

```
template <typename Container>
inline void printcontainer(const Container &container)
```

Note that I changed the argument to `const` reference to avoid an unnecessary copy.

You can generalize your print function to C arrays by using the non-member `std::begin` and `std::end` or by using a [range based `for` loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for):

```
template <typename Container>
inline void printcontainer(const Container &container) {
    for (const auto &v : container)
        std::cout << v << "\n";
}
```

OT remark: You probably do not need the `inline` here.

Comment: wow i'm very impressed by ` for (const auto &v : container)` how's this called? I'll study it

Comment: [Range-based for loop (since C++11)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)

Comment: tyvm, i'll accept this answer as soon as so allows!

Comment: How would you implement this function to print `vector`'s elements from 2nd to `n-2` (`n` is size)? What about `list`? How would you partially print a custom tree container?

Comment: @Drop OP did not ask how to partially print a container, but if one wants to, one can either pass a range-adapter to my function or use iterators as arguments. This answer does work for `std::list` and also works for every decently designed custom tree.

Answer (score 3):

Passing container objects around is against classic Stepanov's STL *container-iterator-algorithm* Generic Programming style.

Usually one would pass iterators:

```
# define ForwardIterator typename // workaround untill we have concepts

template <ForwardIterator It> inline void printcontainer( It begin, It end )
{
    for(;begin != end; ++begin)
    {
        std::cout << *begin << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4};
printcontainer(v.cbegin(), v.cend());
```

Comment: *"You are trying to write Java in C++ files."* How so? I see no problem with passing the container here. In fact, boost provides many container versions of the iterator based functions in the standard library to decrease verbosity. (Not my dv btw.)

Comment: @BaummitAugen Okay, it was a bit too much, I'll remove this phrase ;)

Comment: Whilst this nominally seems OK, that macro is just hideous and deserves a downvote all on its own. Also, screw iterators, ranges are the future.

Comment: @BaummitAugen passing iterators is less verbose when you need to process only a part of the container though. In case of passing by reference you will need to pass two more indices

Comment: C++ is moving toward adopting range based algorithms, a la [Eric Niebler's  library](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3). And passing sub-ranges can be done with [views](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/index.html#range-views) such as `drop`

Comment: @Puppy I saw those macro from [Stepanov's lectures at Amazon A9](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aIHAEYyoTUc). What's wrong with them?

Comment: Even bjarne stroustrup stated that he has a headerfile containing wrapperfunctions for the STL-algorithms that take a container as an argument. c++17 might finally get ranges (and most probably gets array_view), the core guideline support library has spans... there are many examples where ranges are passed as a single argument in modern c++. Passing two iterators might be the most generic way to do things (which was of paramount importance for the STL), but it is far from being the ideal solution if you want to print the contents of a container.

Comment: I was told by some guy from the Standard Committee that ranges are unlikely to be in C++17 and that even Eric Niebler considers ranges proposal incomplete yet (not saying it's the ground truth, just rumors). I wait for ranges myself. I think there should be yet another answer in this thread, with ranges solution. Also, I still don't see the reason for downvoting. Iterators were (and are) the basis of C++ libraries for decades

Comment: @Drop: Don't get me wrong: I don't have a problem with your proposed solution - but the wording somewhat implies that a single parameter version is a bad thing and thats what I (strongly) disagree with. Concerning ranges in c++17: That is somewhat disappointing, but not unexpected (that's why I said *might*) - I've heard that they would get much fewer features into c++1z than originally hoped, but didn't follow the development closely.