# #define as a workaround for missing concepts

Tags: c++, c++-concepts

Is this a good idea for a library implementer to define macro while we are waiting for (hopefully) incoming [concepts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concepts_%28C%2B%2B%29)? What are advantages and disadvantages of this approach?

Examples of macro (by A. Stepanov):

```
#define TotallyOrdered typename
#define Pointer typename
#define Number typename
#define Unsigned typename
#define Integral typename
#define InputIterator typename
#define OutputIterator typename
#define ForwardIterator typename
#define BidirectionalIterator typename
#define RandomAccessIterator typename
...
```

Example usage (from me):

```
template<ForwardIterator It>
It min_element(It first, It last) { ... }
```

The idea:

- while there are no concepts it's a plain old template code
- when concepts will finally arrive, you can delete all macros or rename them if concepts names will differ (you can do this easily in any decent IDE) and then delete or just reimplement these macro into concepts expressions
- take an advantage of future features without rewriting complicated templated code
- even now, "typed" template parameters allow for better code understanding and unlock a possibility to develop static concept-checking tools

<sub>**The long story:**
There are several [series of courses](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aIHAEYyoTUc) by [A. Stepanov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Stepanov) at Amazon A9 where he uses [those macro](https://github.com/rjernst/stepanov-components-course/blob/master/code/lecture1/concepts.h) to substitute `typename` keyword in template parameters lists of the algorithms implemented in the classroom. Charmed by this "pointer-oriented programmer" and an old guru of all C++ libraries I started to use those macro everywhere. Recently I was pointed out that [macro are ugly (and, also, that iterators are kinda obsolete, but this is another story)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34561230/1607442). So now I'm looking for other experts suggestions on this approach.</sub>

<sub>**Examples of libraries in question**: a GPU-accelerated version of Standard library (with hight perf computing stuff like structs of arrays, zipped iterators etc.) , a linear algebra library, a tree-like data structure, new algorithm functions</sub>

Comment: A big drawback is that by doing so you globally 'reserve' identifiers such as `RandomAccessIterator` and so on. I've seen them in use pre-concepts and used them myself.

Comment: If you really want to do this, you should probably at least mark them as placeholders.  `ForwardIterator_Placeholder` or `ForwardIteratorPlaceholder` documents that it's a note to self that currently does nothing, while `ForwardIterator` could be confused as the _actual_ ForwardIterator concept.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One massive disadvantage is that your code will be *lying*.

---

**What I prefer**

The code does not use concepts at all, but you can alter it to use them in the future if/when they exist.

**What I don't prefer**

The code does not use concepts at all, but *looks like it does*. Can't imagine anything much more dangerous than this. What a massive sense of false security that's going to imbue upon maintainers!

---

Your idea won't work anyway. When concepts come along, you'll inevitably discover that you've made some mistakes somewhere that couldn't possibly have been diagnosed by your older compiler. *You're still going to have to change your code*.

For now, just document the preconditions/constraints for your types, as you've always done.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, this does not sound like a good idea. The standard often uses the **name** of the template argument to describe the properties it's expected to have. So, for example, the algorithm `all_of` is described as

```
template <class InputIterator, class Predicate>
bool all_of(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, Predicate pred);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might just want to have simply one macro, say `CONCEPTS`, and use it in code like this:

```
#ifdef CONCEPTS
// you concept based code
#else
// your temp workaround code
#endif
```

that way you can use your build facility (*eg* makefile) to control whether or not concepts are used.

Comment: Sorry it wasn't clear from the question but idea was to expand each macro to something meaningful (and different for each concept) and to not rewrite code twice. I will add this to the question.